# After deleting rows on multiple selection of checkbox not getting values of $_GET?

Tags: php, mysql

i'm deleting products(data) on checkbox and after click on delete button i'm deleting rows but the problem is after delete is complete i'm not getting $_GET global array variable values back to my page which is essential to load page...
$_GET['cid'] is category id and $_GET['scid'] is subcategory id...just because of missing values my page is showing up without data

```
if(isset($_GET['delete']))
{
    $cnt=array();
    $cnt=count($_GET['chkbox']);
    for($i=0;$i<$cnt;$i++)
    {
        $del_id=$_GET['chkbox'][$i];
        $query="delete from products where product_id=".$del_id;
        mysqli_query($con,$query);
        header("Location:topics.php?cid=".$_GET['cid']."&scid=".$_GET['scid']."");}}
```

on header location i'm not getting value ,
plz ignore if u found any mistake in my questioning because this is my first question

Comment: What is the URL used when accessing this code in the first place?  Can you show a more complete example to include how this code is reached?  Also, be aware that your code is wide open to SQL injection, which means you're executing any SQL code any user sends you.  You're also not checking for SQL errors, and are very likely to have some, so there's no telling what could be happening here.

Comment: @David URL ::http://localhost/php/FORM%20LOGIN/topics.php?cid=1&scid=5

Comment: Then this code isn't running in the first place because `isset($_GET['delete'])` will be false.  Your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @David no delete operation is working fine but i'm having redirecting problem

Comment: "delete" is a button so on it's press delete is happening

Comment: The information you have provided indicates that the problem is somewhere else.  If you want to find the problem then you're going to have to stop assuming that your code is working when it clearly and demonstrably is not.  Debug your code more to at least find where the problem is happening, because the information you have provided does not demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @David after selecting items when i clicked on delete button items are deleting and also i'm redirecting to topics.php but i'm not getting data of cid and scid..

Comment: before i click delete button:localhost/php/FORM%20LOGIN/topics.php?cid=1&scid=5    when i clicked delete button:http://localhost/php/FORM%20LOGIN/topics.php?cid=&scid=

Comment: Ok, and notice in that URL when you click the button... There are no `cid` or `scid` values.  You can't use values that you don't have.  Provide those values in that URL and you can use them.

Comment: @David actually i'm new at coding i really don't know how to get those values into header link

Comment: How do you get them into the URL in the first place?  Where do those values come from?  Why are they not in the second URL?  As stated, multiple times, *the problem is somewhere else*.  So step one would be to find where the problem is.

Comment: Also, according to that second URL, there is still no `delete` value in the query string.  So `isset($_GET['delete'])` *will still be false* and this block of code *will not run*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the information provided, I'm going to *assume* that this is the problem and hopefully this can be helpful...

Presumably you have a form of some kind which you access via your URL: `localhost/php/FORM%20LOGIN/topics.php?cid=1&scid=5`

```
<form method="GET">
    // some form elements
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

Something at least similar to that.  Then when you click the delete button you send a request to a URL which is more like: `localhost/php/FORM%20LOGIN/topics.php?delete=Delete&...`

So your original `cid` and `scid` values are lost.  This is because they weren't included in the form.  But since you had those values when the page loaded, you can include them in your form.  Something like this:

```
<form method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" name="cid" value="<?php echo $_GET['cid']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="scid" value="<?php echo $_GET['scid']; ?>" />
    // some form elements
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

By including the values in your form, they will be included in the form's request to the server.

Comment: thank you very much...now it's working perfectly